# Python TCPServer Address Reuse

Tags: python, tcpserver

```
import SocketServer
import sys
from Queue import *
import threading

class CustomTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, commandQueue=Queue):
        self.queue = commandQueue
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=False)
        SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
        self.server_bind()
        self.server_activate()

class SingleTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        commandQueue = self.server.queue
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        try:
            commandQueue.put(self.data)
        except Queue.Empty:
            print 'Sorry.. Cannot accept any more.. Queue is full..'

def main():
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 50099
    commandQueue = Queue()
    server = CustomTCPServer((HOST, PORT), SingleTCPHandler, commandQueue)
    threadObject = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
        threadObject.setDaemon(True)
        threadObject.start()
    threadObject.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

But whenever I run the code for second time I get the message that
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

I am confused..

Any suggestion would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
```

Which sets the value on the base class that you've already subclassed yourself from, (and created an instance of),

Use:

```
self.allow_reuse_address = True
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in practise - I can set this in my __init__ and still experience the Errno 98 error. UPDATE: After reviewing the SocketServer source I realised it's because I set the property *after* calling super(...).__init__, and it needs to be set before (in the case where bind_and_activate is set to true).

Comment: No matter if I put it before or after the call to `super.__init__`, this does not work in Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're ever closing the socket at the end. Try adding a `server.shutdown()` (as well as changing the `allow_reuse_address`) to shut it down at the end after the thread join.